# Cursor not displaying in UISearchBar for our app

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

For the UISearchBars in our app, there's no cursor shown in the bar with focus when running under iOS 7.  How do we make that show?

We are using the SDK 7, with a minimum target of 6.  We do have the translucency off for the navigation bars, and set the color at runtime.  I can't think of anything else we are doing differently.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Our problem was that the tint color was set to white, so I didn't see it.

Comment: If you want cursor to be different color from buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42444940/4754881

Comment: same problem.. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

Set

```
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: The color of the search bar seems to be (66, 107, 242) fwiw

Answer (score 7):

In  the searchbox property window

open View Section>Set Tint color - default.

[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it can be done in Swift :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as! UIView
    let subViewsArray = view.subviews

    for (subView: UIView) in subViewsArray as! [UIView] {
        println(subView)
        if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
            subView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is my Xamarin C# port: UIView view = searchBar.Subviews[0];

            foreach (UIView item in view.Subviews)
            {
                if (item is UITextField)
                {
                    item.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
                }
            }

Answer (score 2):

```
searchBar.tintColor = view.tintColor  // self.view usually has the proper tintColor
```

Better than `.blue` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tintColor for UISearchBar, in your storyboard, xib or code. Xcode seems to ignore the default tintColor.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the searchBars subviews and obtain the uitextfield subview and set its @"insertionPointColor" value to your desired color. Works but is private api

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [[(UITextField *) subView valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
    }
}
```