# Cursor invisible in UISearchBar iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have `UISearchBar` in `UITableView` as a table header. When I push the `UISearchBar` for start searching, this method is being triggered

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

for `UISearchDisplayController`.

But result is like that;

[image]

As you can see, there is no cursor, I can start typing and search, everything works fine. Also it's invisible only in iOS 7. However, with iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.1 Beta 3 I could see the cursor. So how can I make UISearchBar cursor visible or how can I add cursor in my UISearchBar?

Comment: Any chance you are setting `tintColor` somewhere trying to change the color of the wrapping UI? If so, that can cause the cursor issue you are seeing ([potential solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386608/48700)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cursor in the search bar takes color from Search Bar -> View -> Tint Color property.
In your case, it is set to White color, so it becomes invisible.

Comment: In normal condition, you are right but it doesn't work for me. I solved this problem with create original iOS SearchBar.

Comment: If you want change only cursor color, you can use this:
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .black

Answer (score 8):

try using with

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.navigationItem.titleView.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 7):

Try setting text field tint color using UIAppearance

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Comment: What's the equivalent swift?

Answer (score 3):

**If you want the cursor and cancel button to be different colors...**

---

Start by setting the view's tint color (not the bar tint) in the storyboard editor, which will be applied to both the cursor and cancel button.

[image: UISearchBar in storyboard editor with simulator.]

---

To make the cursor a different color, you need to do it programatically. The text field is nested a couple levels down in the searchBar's subviews. Use this `setTextFieldTintColor` helper function to traverse all of the subviews.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set tint color for all subviews in searchBar that are of type UITextField
    setTextFieldTintColor(to: UIColor.darkText, for: searchBar)
}    

func setTextFieldTintColor(to color: UIColor, for view: UIView) {
    if view is UITextField {
        view.tintColor = color
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        setTextFieldTintColor(to: color, for: subview)
    }
}
```

---

The end result looks like this:

[image: UISearchBar with different colored cursor and cancel button.]

Answer (score 3):

Try this it's only one line of code to solve your problem , Change cursor **tintColor** property white to blue.

```
  searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Hope this will help to someone .

Answer (score 2):

Your cursor is white because your tintColor property on UISearchBar is set to white.

If you want Cancel btn to be white, but cursor to be black you can use:
`UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .black`