# Changing cursor color on UISearchBar without changing tintColor

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, tintcolor

I want my searchBar's tint color to be white (meaning the cancel button be white). The cursor is not visible when the tint color is white. Is there a way to set cursor color separately?

Comment: I posted a solution with detailed screenshots here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42444940/4754881

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Set your tint color to the color you want the cancel button to be and then use the [UIAppearance Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to change the tint color on the text field to be the color you wish the cursor to be. Ex:

```
[self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];                
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Comment: Don't know why, by this code (second line) changes also tint for barButton in next modal scene. So I used @Felipe's answer below.

Comment: I had the same problem as tzaloga. Anyone any idea why this affects modal scene's bar button item color?

Comment: since iOS13, you can use searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor

Answer (score 17):

## Swift 3.0 and 4 version

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white        
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: searchController.searchBar)]).tintColor = .black
```

Note that searchBar can't be optional.

Answer (score 13):

If you're fond of functional, yet annoying one-liners in Swift, I got Benjamin's for loop down to this:

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

searchController.searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.flatMap(){ $0 as? UITextField }.first?.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Answer (score 8):

**Easiest in Swift 5:**

```
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .black
```

Comment: Great! Working!

Answer (score 6):

Compact Swift 2.0 solution using *for-where* syntax (no need to break loop):

```
// Make SearchBar's tint color white to get white cancel button.
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white()

// Loop into it's subviews and find TextField, change tint color to something else.
for subView in searchBar.subviews[0].subviews where subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField) {
        subView.tintColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, when I wanted to change cursor color for only one searchBar.

Answer (score 5):

```
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
for ( UIView *v in [searchBar.subviews.firstObject subviews] )
{
    if ( YES == [v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] )
    {
        [((UITextField*)v) setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This seemed to work for me in swift as well.

```
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([searchController.searchBar.dynamicType]).tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Comment: Both Felipe & Eric's solutions work for me but I feel more comfortable with your solution Eric.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking to do the same in Swift, here is a solution I came accros after quite a lot of trouble :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as! UIView
    let subViewsArray = view.subviews

    for (subView: UIView) in subViewsArray as! [UIView] {
        println(subView)
        if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
            subView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just add an extension to UISearchBar with the following code.

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var cursorColor: UIColor! {
        set {
            for subView in self.subviews[0].subviews where ((subView as? UITextField) != nil) {
                subView.tintColor = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            for subView in self.subviews[0].subviews where ((subView as? UITextField) != nil) {
                return subView.tintColor
            }
            // Return default tintColor
            return UIColor.eightBit(red: 1, green: 122, blue: 255, alpha: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## iOS 9 and above

The easiest way to set a tintColor different for cancel button and textField, use this:

```
[self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTintColor:UIColor.blueColor];
```

Comment: You are missing a [ at the start of your first line... Should be : [self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest solution.

```
let textField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField

    textField.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: `let textField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField;
 textField?.tintColor = UIColor.white` avoids forced unwrapping and thereby any unwanted crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "functional" version of Felipe's answer (Swift 4.2)

```
// Make SearchBar's tint color white to get white cancel button.
searchBar.tintColor = .white

// Get the TextField subviews, change tint color to something else.
if let textFields = searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UITextField }) {
        textFields.forEach { $0.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray }
}
```