# UISearchBar set different tint color for cancel button

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

In my swift app I have a search bar like this:

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
searchBar.spellCheckingType = .No
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .None
searchBar.autocorrectionType = .No
searchBar.placeholder = "Suchbegriff eingeben ..."
searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

How can I set another tint color for cancel button as the tint color for the whole search bar?

Comment: I posted an answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42444940/4754881

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found the solution:

```
let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as UIView
let subViewsArray = view.subviews

   for subView: UIView in subViewsArray {
       if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
          subView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you have to access the button subview, and then change its color, you can do that like this:

```
  for subview in searchBar.subviews {
            if subview is UIButton { //checking if it is a button
                subview.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I hadn't tested it, but I see you have solved it using the loop part, I had forgotten that there was more then one layer of subviews:)

Answer (score 1):

use the keyPath:

when accessing it when hooked up to a searchController-

```
// this is what worked for me
let cancelButton = searchController.searchBar.value(forKeyPath: "cancelButton") as? UIButton
cancelButton?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

when not-

```
let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKeyPath: "cancelButton") as? UIButton
cancelButton?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```